# Custom Item Delegate Resizing and Interaction

Tags: python, pyside

I'm creating a custom item delegate for a news feed I'm trying to create in pyside. I'm not quite sure how to make the textEdit auto adjust it's size to fit the contents of the text it's wrapping and secondly maintain the Text Interaction feature, where users can click and highlight text?

This is what I'm currently getting and you can see the text boxes are being drawn overtop and not vertically being sized correctly:

[image]

```
import os, sys
from Qt import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui


class NewsItem(object):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(NewsItem, self).__init__()
        self.title = kwargs.get('title', '')
        self.date = kwargs.get('date', '')
        self.content = kwargs.get('content', '')


class NewsItemDelegate(QtWidgets.QItemDelegate):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(NewsItemDelegate, self).__init__(parent)


    def paint(self, painter, option, index):
        # rect = option.rect.adjusted(1, 1, -1, -1)
        # painter.fillRect(rect, QtGui.QColor(20,40,170,50))
        # QtWidgets.QItemDelegate.paint(self, painter, option, index)

        # get data from userrole
        data = index.data(role=QtCore.Qt.UserRole)

        # Main Widget
        title = QtWidgets.QLabel(data.title)
        content = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(data.content)
        content.setFixedHeight(content.sizeHint().height())

        widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        layout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(widget)
        layout.addWidget(title, 0, 0)
        layout.addWidget(content, 1, 0)
        widget.setGeometry(option.rect)

        widget.render(painter, option.rect.topLeft())

        # painter.save()
        # painter.restore()


    def sizeHint(self, option, index):
        return QtCore.QSize(100, 50)
        return QtWidgets.QItemDelegate.sizeHint(self, option, index)


class NewsModel(QtGui.QStandardItemModel):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        QtGui.QStandardItemModel.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)


class NewsListView(QtWidgets.QListView):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(NewsListView, self).__init__(parent)

        self.setModel(NewsModel(self))
        self.setItemDelegate(NewsItemDelegate(self))
        self.setEditTriggers(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.NoEditTriggers)
        self.setSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred)


    def setNewsItems(self, lst):
        self.model().clear()
        for x in lst:
            item = QtGui.QStandardItem()
            # item.setData(x.title, role=QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole)
            item.setData(x, role=QtCore.Qt.UserRole)
            self.model().appendRow(item)


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.resize(350, 500)

        # Controls
        self.uiListView = NewsListView()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.uiListView)


    def unitTest(self):
        self.uiListView.setNewsItems([
            NewsItem(title='Big Update', date='Today', content='Something goes here...'),
            NewsItem(title='Smaller Update', date='Yesterday', content='Something goes here which should support word wrap'),
            NewsItem(title='Another Update', date='Last Year', content='Something goes here...'),
            NewsItem(title='Old Update', date='Unknown', content='Something goes here...'),
        ])


def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = MainWindow()
    ex.unitTest()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: What Custom Item Delegate? I do not see that you have not implemented anything. Also the model you have implemented is very rare, why do not you use the QStandardItem? QStandardItemModel provides the data in sight through the delegate through the data method, but by default the data method uses the QStandardItem information, but you do not have any

Comment: well as you can see, im not entirely sure how to achieve my desired goal. I just noticed i was using a style delegate. I'm guessing that is not correct. I can certainly use the QStandardItem and/or QStandardItemModel  i just don't know how to achieve what i want. Can you help point me in the right direction?

Comment: @eyllanesc i updated my question based on your feedback, im just having some painting issues and interaction issues if you could help.

Answer (score 0):

In this type of cases is to create a widget as an editor, and for this you must make in the paint method call openPersistentEditor(). The createEditor(), setEditorData() and setModelData() methods must also be overwritten.

```py
# ...
from functools import partial
# ...
class EditorWidget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    editingFinished = QtCore.Signal()

    def __init__(self, data=None, parent=None):
        super(EditorWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        self.title_label = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        self.content_textedit = QtWidgets.QTextEdit()
        self.content_textedit.textChanged.connect(self.editingFinished)
        lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        lay.addWidget(self.title_label)
        lay.addWidget(self.content_textedit)
        if data is not None:
            self.data = data

    @property
    def data(self):
        return NewsItem(
            title=self.title_label.text(),
            content=self.content_textedit.toPlainText(),
        )

    @data.setter
    def data(self, d):
        self.title_label.setText(d.title)
        tc = self.content_textedit.textCursor()
        self.content_textedit.setPlainText(d.content)
        self.content_textedit.setTextCursor(tc)


class NewsItemDelegate(QtWidgets.QItemDelegate):
    def paint(self, painter, option, index):
        if isinstance(self.parent(), QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView):
            self.parent().openPersistentEditor(index)

    def createEditor(self, parent, option, index):
        data = index.data(QtCore.Qt.UserRole)
        editor = EditorWidget(data, parent)
        wrapper = partial(self.commitData.emit, editor)
        editor.editingFinished.connect(wrapper)
        model = index.model()
        model.setData(index, editor.sizeHint(), QtCore.Qt.SizeHintRole)
        return editor

    def setEditorData(self, editor, index):
        data = index.data(QtCore.Qt.UserRole)
        editor.data = data

    def setModelData(self, editor, model, index):
        model.setData(index, editor.data, QtCore.Qt.UserRole)
# ...
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the help. Is it possible to make the textedit resize vertically to fit the contents of it's text after doing wordwrap

Comment: @JokerMartini I do not understand you, explain yourself better. You could show a picture of what you want

Comment: Is there a way to make the TextEdit widgets auto resize to minimum height required to display all the contained text inside of it?